# WSUS defered reboot

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, windows-update, wsus

I am trying to find a way of allowing my users to defer the reboot after updates have been applied for 4 days and then force a reboot if they have not already rebooted in that time.

Please correct me if I am wrong but from looking around it seems that this is not possible using MS tools.  Is there a third party tool or script (that can’t be killed from taskmgr) that I can use that will do this?

I am running a 2008 WSUS server on a 2003 domain and any help at all would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to defer the "automatic reboot"? Or just allow them to manually reboot without processing updates that have been installed?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can schedule installation for another day of week. if you want to.

Use Group Policy Objects to configure that.

Look at this directive:

```
 [Computer\Adminstrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Update\Configure Automatic Updates]
```

Answer (score 0):

WSUS doesn't really have the level of control over reboots that you're looking for, at least not using Group Policy. I'm not sure how you would even get close to this using the policies available.

You could just schedule the updates for a specific day and time using the 'Configure Windows Updates' policy, then schedule a reboot four days later as a scheduled task. You might even be able to make the reboot conditional on there being a reboot pending.